# Is SVM a good choice for multi-class text classification with a dictionary of related words?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, training-data, text-classification

i want to classify set of articles (textual content) to categories like {sport,politcs,tech etc...}
i searched for machine learning algorithms to make the classify mission. i choose svm for this mission But not sure about training way.

i choose svm because i see some article describe the performance of svm in classify a textual contents.
for training the model i think to Collect a set of articles including their classification (Labels)
in addition i will create a dictionary of two columns : category and related words to category
for example for sport category there will be related words like {football,basketball,championship,...}
the dictionary will help the model for extract features from articles. maybe i will use TF-IDF to help the model To determine the importance or weight of the word.

i know svm in its basic version it is intended to be classified into two categories but i see also that can be used for classify for multiclasses also

questions :

1. should i change my model for another one like KNN or neural networks or svm good also ?
2. the dictionary can really help to accurate my model classification ?

Comment: may someone help me plz